# Layer-Cake for general functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

The Layer-Cake representation of a non-negative measureable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$f(x) = \int^{\infty}_{0} \mathbb{I}_{\{y\ \in\ \mathbb{R}^n|f(y)>t\}}(x)\ dt$$
Can this be generalized to functions that are not necessarily non-negative. For a non-positive function $-f$ will do. But what about the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For measurable $f$, I think that

$$f(x) = \int^{\infty}_{0} \mathbb{I}_{\{y\ \in\ \mathbb{R}^n|f(y)>t\}}(x)\ dt - \int^{\infty}_{0} \mathbb{I}_{\{y\ \in\ \mathbb{R}^n|f(y)<-t\}}(x)\ dt$$

should work.