# Generalisation of Chebyshev's inequality (reference request)

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, reference-request

I know the very famous Chebyshev's inequality in measure theory which states that for a measure space $X$ and a non negative constant $t$,
$$\mu(\{x \in X : |f(x)| > t\}) \leq \frac{1}{t}\int_{X} |f|d \mu.$$
Wikipedia also [mentions without citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_statement) a more general inequality saying that if g is non negative and non decreasing function with $g(0) \neq 0$ then
\begin{equation*}\mu(\{x \in X : |f(x)| > t\})  \leq \frac{1}{g(t)}\int_{X} g (|f|)d \mu. \end{equation*}
I tried to search internet for a reference of this inequality, but I couldn't find one. If anyone can provide me a refrence for this, it will be very helpful.

Comment: this $\mu(\{x \in X : |f(x)| > t\}) \leq \frac{1}{t}\int_{X} |f|d \mu$ is not Chebyshev's inequality, it is the Markov's inequality

Comment: I have heard both names used for this inequality depending on whether you're in probability or measure theory

Comment: I mentioned the required argument in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4138329/80734) somewhat related answer; it in fact follows from the standard Chebyshev. Since the proof is so straightforward, I'm not sure if there is a published book source. Perhaps also consider the related ["layer-cake decomposition"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478123/layer-cake-for-general-functions) which is mentioned in Lieb-Loss's Analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://rc476.user.srcf.net/probability/prob_ineq.v1.1.pdf) might help, see the second page ("General Tail Estimate")

The proof goes in a very similar way to the "regular" Chebyshev's (Markov's) inequality.

The equality below is because $g$ is increasing and the inequality is by Chebyshev's inequality
$$ \mu(\{|f| \geq t\}) = \mu(\{g(|f|) \geq g(t)\})\leq \frac{1}{g(t)} \int_X g(|f|) d\mu$$